# (dockerfile) for flag -v: bad mode specified

Tags: docker

I have problems with the introduction of these instructions https://github.com/notabenoid/notabenoid-dockerfile

Out my error command

```
 docker run -v `pwd`:/srv/example.com -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 --name notabenoid notabenoid
```

I managed to turn the site, but my goal is to change a few files and pictures

*How to edit files to container ?*

Comment: I guess you wrote a typo, as there should be a space between pwd and :/srv/example.com

Answer (score 0):

use `docker exec`to modify some files in a container, see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

check also the docs for `docker run`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

and the examples with `-v`

Answer (score 0):

If You only need to change some files use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 --name notabenoid notabenoid
docker cp notabenoid:/srv/example.com/file_to_change .
edit file
docker cp file_to_change notabenoid:/srv/example.com/file_to_change
```

where `/srv/example.com/file_to_change` is a path to file in container.

### edit

Let's Your new logo is `/home/Hellioob/new_logo.gif`.

```
docker cp /home/Hellioob/new_logo.gif notabenoid:/notabenoid/site/www/i/logo.gif
```

Comment: Works. Change `/srv/example.com/file_to_change` to proper path to file in container which You want to copy.

Comment: sorry! i am amateur! http://i.imgur.com/UfJLVtS.png as I want to change the logo on notabenoid\www\i  sorry but I'm new and I do not know what exactly to do more